# Problems with LOAD DATA INFILE With and Without LOCAL

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a website, which is running PHP 5.3.3 (Apache) and MySQLI 5.1.73

mysqli.allow_local_infile is set to ON

I am trying to get the following statement to run:

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" . $data_location . "' INTO TABLE " . $table_name . " FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES

The folder set up is as follows:

Root

```
/data/

/httpdocs/
    import.php
```

$data_location = /data/filename.csv

The line of code is in import.php

Please note, I have tested the whole script on a dummy server and it worked 100%. I have also tested the script on the real server and everything works apart from this line.

In context, the lines of code that are relevant are:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, NAME) or die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());

$load_data_query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" . $data_location . "' INTO TABLE " . $table_name . " FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES";

$load_data_result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $load_data_query);//Run the query
```

When I don't include the word LOCAL the error I get is Access Denied for (USER @ HOST)

When I include the word LOCAL, the error I get is The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

Can anyone help? (Please note, it's a live server so we have to stick with the current server setup)

Comment: What is $database_connection ?  It declared nowhere

Comment: Ah sorry, it was pulled out of a function, thanks for noticing, I'll change it. It's $mysqli